# Cannot call ERC20 mint function from another contract's payable function

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, openzeppelin

Scenario:  Contract A is a contract that sells ERC20 tokens Specified in Contract A using Open Zeppelin's ERC20 implementation.

Contract A has a payable function that receives ether from a caller, as payment, and then calculates how many units of Contract B's token is mintable for that payment.

```
// Inside Contract B, the ERC20 contract
 function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner { 
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
```

**Note:**  Contract A is the Owner of Contract B.

```
// Inside contract A....
function pay() external payable {
        uint256 numTokens = calculateTokens(msg.value);
        minter.mint(msg.sender, numTokens);  // minter is a ref to the ERC20 contract.
}

receive() external payable {
     uint numTokens = calculateTokens(msg.value);
     minter.mint(msg.sender, numTokens);
 }
```

No fallback() is implemented as I am calling `pay()`.  For the same reason, I don't expect the `receive()` to be triggered either.

Question: Can Contract A’s payable function call Contract B’s non-payable `mint` function?

Remix says no :  reverts this transaction and says I cannot send value to a non payable function…

Answer (score 0):

We can't see your whole contract but it might be because your contract A does not have a payable fallback function in order to receive tokens.

Adding

```
receive() external payable {}
```

Or

```
fallback() external payable {}
```

Should be enough

Comment: Thanks @cheen! Updated my question to include the receive(). It was there, but have included it in the question now.

As i understand it, the fallback is only where there is NO receive function **and** when there is calldata.  Since I'm trying to call pay(), there is calldata, and the the receive should not trigger, nor the fallback.